# Keep trying of an API key between requests [flask and flask_restful]

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful, flask-session

The current I issue I currently have is how to keep track of an API key that is stored in a MySQL database. Each backend I have is living in it's own file.

```py
api.add_resource(SQL, "/get/<string:name>/<string:hash>/<string:id>/<string:key>/<string:dep>") 
api.add_resource(Sync, "/sync/post")
api.add_resource(Update, "/update")
api.add_resource(Login, "/login")
```

SQL from `sql.py`, Sync from `sync.py`, etc. And I'm not too sure how I'm supposed to keep track the API key. From my research, it shows that I need to use something called a session. But I'm not sure how I can get it to work. After looking at some [documentation](https://flask-session.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it seems that it needs everything to be in one file. But I wouldn't know anyways. Since following the website's instructions one-to-one doesn't work, as `from flask.ext.session import session` will give an error: `module flask.ext.session does not exist`, or something along the lines of unable to find module.

And I don't want to keep all my classes in one file because each class is at least 50 lines long, with one of them having over 150 lines. Which is what made me split each backend into their own files in the first place.

I've also tried making a `Host` class which inherits from all my backends. And with `SQL.__init__(self, key)` and `Sync.__init__(self, key)`, and so on. My initial theory was that in each of my backend class' constructors I can make a variable `self.key = key`. But that didn't work either. Because of circular imports, which can be fixed if I just put all my backend classes into the same file. Which again, is not what I want.

Comment: What do you mean by "keep track" of an API Key? Do you need to access the API Key in your resources?

Comment: Yeah. You need the API key to access every resource.